# Terminal python tic-tac-toe game

Tags: python, beginner, object-oriented, game, console

As someone that started to learn basic python programming, I decided to make a Python tic-tac-toe game for the terminal, to develop my OOP skills.

I would like to know if my code has a lot of repetition and if it could have been done in a shorter, cleaner, faster, more efficient and more elegant way.

```
import re
import numpy as np
 
class Board_Game():

    def __init__(self):
        
        self.first_row = " 1 | 2 | 3"
        self.second_row = " 4 | 5 | 6"
        self.third_row = " 7 | 8 | 9"
        
        self.rows = [self.first_row,
                     self.second_row,
                     self.third_row ]
        
        self.markers = {'X': [],
                        'O': []}
        
        self.positions = [1, 2, 3,
                          4 ,5 ,6,
                          7, 8, 9]

        self.avaliable_positions = [1, 2, 3,
                                    4 ,5 ,6,
                                    7, 8, 9]
    

    def print_board_coordinates(self):
        
        print('Board Coordinates:\n')
        print(" " + self.first_row)
        print(" ---|---|---")
        print(" " + self.second_row)
        print(" ---|---|---")
        print(" " + self.third_row)
        print('\n')


    def _render_row_state(self, row, marker):

        for k in marker.keys():
            for v in marker[k]:
                row = row.replace(str(v), k)
        row = re.sub(r'\d', ' ', row)
        
        return row


    def print_board(self):

        row_states = []
        for i , r in enumerate(self.rows):
            temp = self._render_row_state(r, self.markers)
            row_states.append(temp)
        
        print('Board:\n')
        print("    |   |    ")
        print(" " + row_states[0])
        print("----|---|----")
        print(" " + row_states[1])
        print("----|---|----")
        print(" " + row_states[2])
        print("    |   |    ")
        print('\n')


    def mark_board(self, marker, position):

        _valid_play = 0

        while _valid_play != 1:

            if marker not in ['X', 'O']:
                print('Wrong marker try again!')

            elif position not in self.positions or position not in self.avaliable_positions:
                position = int(input('Invalid move, choose another position\n'))

            else:    
                _valid_play = 1
                print("Valid play")
                self.markers[marker].append(position)
                self.avaliable_positions.remove(position)

        return position


class Player():
    
    def __init__(self, marker, first_play = False):
        
        assert marker in ['X', 'O'], f'Marker not allowed'
        
        self.marker = marker

        self._first_play = first_play
        self.owned_positions = []
        self.adversary_positions = []
        self.avaliable_positions = [1, 2, 3,
                                    4, 5, 6,
                                    7, 8, 9]
        self.winner = False


    def __repr__(self):
        return "Player()"


    def __str__(self):
        return f"Player {self.marker}"


    def make_move(self, position):

        mark = self.marker
        return mark, position


    def ack_own_position(self, position):

        self.owned_positions.append(position)


    def look_adversary_position(self, position):

        self.adversary_positions.append(position)


    def look_game_board(self, avaliable_positions):

        self.avaliable_positions = avaliable_positions


class Game():

    def __init__(self, players, board):
        self._players = players
        self._board = board
        self.winning_condition = [[1, 2, 3],
                                  [4, 5, 6], 
                                  [7, 8, 9], 
                                  [1, 4, 7],
                                  [2, 5, 8],
                                  [3, 6, 9],
                                  [1, 5, 9],
                                  [3, 5, 7]]   
        self.game_won = False
        self.play_count = 0
        self.game_winning_outcome = None


    def choose_first_player(self, first_player: int):
        """
        """

        self._players[first_player]._first_play = True
        self._first_player = first_player + 1
        self._player_time = first_player


    def _change_player_time(self):
        """
        """

        self._player_time = (self._player_time + 1) % 2
        self.play_count += 1


    def _check_winning_condition(self, player):
        """
        """

        for w in self.winning_condition:
            if set(w).issubset(player.owned_positions):
                player.winner = True
                print('Player', player.marker, 'has won')
                self.game_won = True
                self.game_winning_outcome = player.marker
                break

        if self.play_count == 8 and  not self.game_won:
            self.game_winning_outcome = "Draw"
            print('DRAW!!!')

    
    def _play_game(self, position):
        """
        """
        
        _player = self._players[self._player_time]
        _other_player = self._players[(self._player_time + 1) % 2]
        _move = _player.make_move(position)
        _mark = _player.marker    
        
        # Actions
        new_position = self._board.mark_board(_mark, position)

        _player.ack_own_position(new_position)
        _other_player.look_adversary_position(new_position)

        self._check_winning_condition(_player)



# Main Game

# Game beggining who plays first and markers attribution
print('\nPlayer 1 choose between markers X or O')
game_markers = ['X', 'O']

marker_player_1 = input('')

dumb_player_count = 0
while marker_player_1 not in game_markers:
    print('You didnt chose a valid marker try again!')
    marker_player_1 = input('')
    dumb_player_count += 1
    if dumb_player_count == 2:
        exit('You are boring go play Tibia!')


player_1 = Player(marker_player_1)
marker_player_2 = [_ for _ in game_markers if _ != marker_player_1][0]
player_2 = Player(marker_player_2)


print(f'\nPlayer 1 marker: {player_1.marker}')
print(f'Player 2 marker: {player_2.marker}\n')

board = Board_Game()
game = Game([player_1, player_2], board)


print('Are you going to choose who plays first or should we chose randomly?')
_ = input('press R for randomly picking the first player:\n')

if _ in ['r', 'R']:
    idx = np.random.choice([0, 1])
    game.choose_first_player(idx) 
    print(f"\nPlayer {idx + 1} plays first")


else:
    _ = input('Press 1 if you want to Player 1 to start:\n')

    if _ == '1':
        game.choose_first_player(0) 
        print(f"Player 1 plays first")
    else:
        game.choose_first_player(1) 
        print(f"Player 2 plays first")

stop_game = False

while not stop_game:
    player = game._player_time + 1
    game._board.print_board_coordinates()
    game._board.print_board()
    move = int(input(f'Player {player} choose a position:\n'))
    game._play_game(move)
    game._change_player_time()
    if game.game_won == True or game.game_winning_outcome == 'Draw':
        stop_game = True 

game._board.print_board()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had a quick run through, those are just some of my notes

1. I’d suggest following commonly agreed formatting, I.e. I don’t know if IDE can format arrays the way you have and it may get difficult to maintain.
2. It would be nice to have all class properties defined at the top of the class with a type hint next to each one.
3. `print_board_coordinates` and a board within `print_board` are duplicated, you can extract it out into a PrintBoard class and re-use
4. Within `mark_board, you might be able to get way with just` position not in self.avaliable_positions`within`elif`
5. You can add a class for `Marker` which will figure out for itself if market is allowed or not and then other classes don’t have to care about it.
6. Some of the main code can also be extracted out into a Builder class, that handles setup of the game, and will make testing easier for you
7. Not sure why player needs to know about available positions? I personally would have thought that `owned_possitions` would be sufficient.
8. Given the number of lines, it would be nice to have draw.io diagram that outlines the flow of data in your application. Given the task, I think, communication should be layered with the game class being the mediator.
9. I'd suggest typehinting everything it make it easier for reviewers, such as myself, to understand the subject quicker. Otherwise I have to scroll around and that takes energy.